# How to identify a row with all unique field values in MySql with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, uniqueidentifier

I am really striving hard to get this required result... Anyone's help would be appreciated.

I have this kind of database in MySql:

```
  column_a          column_b     

int_value_1      string_value_1
int_value_2      string_value_2
int_value_3      string_value_3
int_value_4      string_value_4
int_value_5      string_value_5
int_value_6      string_value_6
```

... and I require below as the result:

A row or multiple rows which have the unique values in every column. That row should be unique in every field with every column.

**Something like this:**

```
      column_a                   column_b

1st_unique_int_value      1st_unique_string_value
2nd_unique_int_value      2nd_unique_string_value
```

Now the above row/rows are completely unique with every field in every column.

I tried `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT` and `ARRAY_DIFF` but couldn't get the need fulfilled. Please tell me if you are one of the experts in programming PHP and MySql and can help me out along with the demo, as I am a bit new in this exciting world of programming and development.

Comment: How can you be certain that the number of distinct strings and distinct integer values are the same? And is there always a one-to-one relationships between the values in `column_a` and `column_b`?

Comment: Thanx for your reply Jessen! But the thing is that every single row contains/demonstrates the properties of a single user through its various columns. So the relationship is there and the content of the database works like this only that most of the times there is duplicacy in the rows and I need to find out the unique one for some reason. I would appreciate if you can share your knowledge base and skills to solve this with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ..its working

```
       select * from (
       SELECT col1,col2 FROM `table` group by `col1` having count(col1)=1)x
        JOIN ( SELECT col1,col2 FROM `table` group by `col2` having count(col2)=1
         )y ON x.col1 = y.col1 and x.col2=y.col2
```

Comment: Thank you so very much Mr. Ajit. Your snippet actually worked out pretty well and it does complete the requirement of finding the UNIQUE row in the db. GOD Bless You!